# How to expand and collapse the column in table using PrimeNG angular

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-datatable, primeng-dropdowns, primeng-table

I need to expand and collapse the column in table using PrimeNG angular

need to expand and collapse the column in table using PrimeNG angular.

need to expand and collapse the column in table using PrimeNG angular.

I need to expand and collapse the column in table using PrimeNG angular

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.